# undefined method playVideo (actionScript)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to control my video(flash player) via javascript,

But I have problem in my action script part, would you please help me

here is my action script:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import fl.video.FLVPlayback;

ExternalInterface.addCallback("playMyVideo", playVideoFromJavaScript);
ExternalInterface.addCallback("pauseMyVideo", pauseVideoFromJavaScript);
```

line 8

```
function playVideoFromJavaScript():void {
flvPlayer.playVideo();
}
```

line 12

```
function pauseVideoFromJavaScript():void {
flvPlayer.pauseVideo();
}
```

and here is the error:

Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 8   1061: Call to a possibly undefined method playVideo through a reference with static type fl.video:FLVPlayback.

Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 12  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method pauseVideo through a reference with static type fl.video:FLVPlayback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fl.video:FLVPlayback` has no `playVideo()` nor `pauseVideo()` method.

Use `play()` and `pause()` instead.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_it/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html